# Which event is called when a user click on a disabled item in optionmenu

Tags: android, optionmenu

I have in my activity an OptionMenu with 3 Buttons. 2 are enabled and 1 disabled.
When I click on a enabled MenuItem I can call a Dialog. But how can I call a Dialog by click on a disabled MenuItem? is it possible?

Which event is calling by clicking on disabled MenuItem?

- onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
- item.setOnMenuItemClickListener()

Doesn't work on disabled Item

- onPrepareOptionMenu(Menu menu) - I don't get the clicked item, only menu

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you will not get any callback for disabled item in option menu. enable menu then only you will get callback

Comment: I do understand your answer, it's very easy to do so. To be honest, I doubt a bit, but it looks more like a comment suggesting the answer, and it was already flagged as "low quality". If you don't know how this works, after your answer is flagged "low quality" several people will review, if majority agrees is moved to a comment (so other people can use the info to write a detailed answer) or deleted. Also, always try to assume good faith and be polite with other people. If I'm and idiot, you don't need to be a jackass, site policy @niks.

Answer (score 0):

First enable that view than you will get callback event.
why are you disabling that view when you want call back on that view.